# how to replace a line in the shell script that contains special characters (eg) URL

Tags: shell, perl, file

I want write shell script to replace a line in the the file and that lines contains special characters (i.e) it contains URL. I tried following approaches

```
sed -i 's/gadgets.url=http://gadgets.abc.com/gadgets.url=http://gadjets-ubuntu2.csez.abccorpin.com:8989/g' test/cm-system.properties

perl -0777 -pi -e 's/gadgets.url=http://gadgets.zoho.com/gadgets.url=http://gadjets-ubuntu2.csez.zohocorpin.com:8989/g' test/cm-system.properties
```

I tried using escape sequence also()
still i cant get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using forward slash (`/`) as a delimiter. You also have slashes in the URL (`http://` part).
You need to escape slashes that are part of the string pattern you are matching:

```
sed -i 's/gadgets.url=http:\/\/gadgets.abc.com/gadgets.url=http:\/\/gadjets-ubuntu2.csez.abccorpin.com:8989/g' test/cm-system.properties
```

Or you could use a different delimiter instead of `/`, e.g. `!`:

```
sed -i 's!gadgets.url=http://gadgets.abc.com!gadgets.url=http://gadjets-ubuntu2.csez.abccorpin.com:8989!g' test/cm-system.properties
```

Comment: thank u @jack the Random, i was breaking my mind for this ....

Comment: @PrabuM please accept the answer if that solves your issue.